# How to get normal json object from Promise Object in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise, react-redux

How to get normal JSON object from Promise Object in react-redux?

My action.js contains:

```
  export function allEmp() {
      let url = "employees?access_token=";
      let result = ApiCall.getApiCall(url)
      .then(function (response) {
         return response;
       })
       .catch(function (error) {
         return error;
       });
       console.log("result",result);
       return {
         type: "ALL_EMP",
         payload: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve(result);
                }, 2000);
            })
       };
     }
```

my API call configuration is:

```
getApiCall(url) {
    let base_url = "http://192.168.1.151:3000/api/";
    let api_token = "1f7169e92c1d0722db575b877707cf0b88b8f0ad";
    let fetch_url = base_url + url + api_token;
    let myHeaders = new Headers({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    return fetch(fetch_url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: myHeaders
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        var error = new Error(response.statusText);
        error.response = response;
        throw error;
      }
    })
    .then(function(json) {
      return json;
     })
  }
```

My store.js :

```
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import promise from "redux-promise-middleware";

import userDetails from "./reducers/User_reducer";

export default createStore(
    combineReducers({
        userDetails
    }),
    {},
    applyMiddleware(thunk, promise())
);
```

But here I'm getting Promise object as a result. So that when I'm assigning in payload it is getting as undefined. How should I manipulate it when I'm sending the response as payload.

Can anyone give me some suggestion?

Comment: This solution is working. But in that example axios has been used and I'm using fetch.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Shubham this method is not working on the post request.  Can you please help ??

export function loginDetails(input) {
  let url = "admins/api_login";
  debugger;
  return (dispatch) => {
   dispatch({type: "LOGIN_FETCH"});
   ApiCall.postApiCall(url, input)
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch({type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: response});
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      dispatch({type: "LOGIN_FAIL", payload: error});
    })
  }
}

Comment: `const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    sessionReducer: state.sessionReducer
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    loginDetails: (login_details, loggedIn, error, payload) => {
      dispatch(loginDetails(login_details, loggedIn, error, payload));
    }
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Signin);`

Comment: `const sessionReducer = (state = {INITIAL_STATE},action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case "LOGIN_FETCH":
      state={
        ...state,
        login_details: action.payload,
        loggedIn: false
      };
      break;
    case "LOGIN_SUCCESS":
      state={
        ...state,
        loggedIn: true,
        error: null
      };
      break;
    case "LOGIN_FAIL":
      state={
        ...state,
        loggedIn: false,
        error: action.payload
      };
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return state;
};
export default sessionReducer;`

Comment: now the problem is API call is not happening.

Comment: Is your loginDetails function getting executed, also is it calling `ApiCall.postApiCall(url, input)`, can you log and check, are there any errors

Comment: `export function loginDetails(input) {
   let url = "admins/api_login";
   let result = ApiCall.postApiCall(url, input)
   .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
    console.log(result);
   return {
     type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS",
     payload: result
   };
 }
`
I've checked like this. It is getting the response. But in dispatch way, it is not happening.

Comment: I see that in your original attempt you have a `debugger;` statement in your original attempt, can you remove that

Comment: till the debugger, it is working. after that debugger its not working.

Comment: Can we discuss in chat??

Comment: Where exactly ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162951/discussion-between-riya-kapuria-and-shubham-khatri).

Answer (score 2):

react-redux does not support asynchronous action creators out-of-the-box, so you'll need to add a dependency to your project.

Take a look at the [redux-thunk middleware](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk), which adds support for asynchronous action creators.

The idea with redux-thunk is that your action creator will trigger another action once the asynchronous code resolves.

In your case, you would have an `allEmp` action creator that calls another action `receiveAllEmp` once the Promise resolves:

**allEmp Action Creator (using redux-thunk)**

```
export function allEmp() {

    return (dispatch) => {

        return ApiCall.getApiCall(url).then((response) => {

            // Dispatch the receiveAllEmp action

            dispatch(receiveAllEmp(response));

            return response;
        });
    };
}
```

**receiveAllEmp Action Creator (normal action creator)**

```
export function receiveAllEmp(response) {
    return {
        type: "ALL_EMP",
        payload: response,
    };
}
```

Comment: Agreed, redux-thunk is great.  But as action creators can dispatch other action creators (potentially as the result of async operations), you can certainly write asynchronous action creators using promises - they just can't return promises.

Answer (score 1):

Promises represent asynchronous processes whose may not be available immediately.  They provide a way to trigger a handler when the result is ready (so your Javascript can go on and get other work done).

To access their result, you place a handler in a `.then` method which is called at resolution and receives the result as an argument.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

You might consider writing your function:

```
export function allEmp() {
  p = new Promise();

  let url = "employees?access_token=";
  ApiCall.getApiCall(url)
  .then(function (response) {
     console.log("result",result);    
     p.resolve({
                type: "ALL_EMP",
                payload: response})
            })
   .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("error",error);  
     p.reject(error)
   });

 return p  // allEmp now returns a promise which gives it a .then() method to contain your handler code.
 }
```

Then call your function like this:

```
allEmp().then(
 function(res){/*handle it here, not called until async resolves, receives result*/},
 function(err){/*or resolves to error, receives error*/}
 )
```

You might consider also having a look at the await/async syntax which makes it appear as if you code is waiting for async operations and can enhance readability in the majority of cases.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Can you please give me an example of syntax?   I've updated the question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer