# How to pass setState to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I'm newbie in React I've built a simple app using Redux & React. I'm just trying to setState in Action.js file and then use it in the component.

The problem is I don't know how to deffiend `errors` argument to `catch setState` and I already deffiend it in the layout component like this

```
this.props.postUsers(this.state.username,this.state.password,this.state.errors)
```

I don't know if this the correct way to pass the setState to another component.

> Note: I'm using redux-promise-middleware it adds _PENDING & _FULFILLED
>   & _REJECTED by it's own.

**src/actions/userActions.js**

```
export function postUsers(username, password, errors) {
    let users = {
        username,
        password,
    };
    let self = this;
    return{
        type: "USERS_POST",
        payload: axios({
            method:'POST',
            url: url,
            data: users,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        })
            .then(success => {
                console.log('sucesssssssss', success)
            })
            .catch(({response}) => {
               self.setState({errors: response.data});
            })

    }
}
```

**src/components/layout.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import { postUsers } from '../actions/usersAction';

class Layout extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            errors: [],
        }
    }
    onUserUpdate(filed, event){
        if (filed === 'username') {
            this.setState({
                username: event.target.value
            });
        }
        if (filed ==='password') {
            this.setState({
                password: event.target.value
            });
        }
    }

    handlePostUsers(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.postUsers(this.state.username,this.state.password,this.state.errors)
    }
    render() {
        console.log('this.state.errors',this.state.errors);
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <input name="username" onChange={this.onUserUpdate.bind(this, 'username')}/>
                <input name="username" onChange={this.onUserUpdate.bind(this, 'password')}/>
                <button onClick={(e) => this.handlePostUsers(e)}>Go ahead</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        act: state.users,
    };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({postUsers}, dispatch)
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(Layout);
```

**src/reducers/userReducers.js**

```
const initalState = {
fetching: false,
fetched: false,
users: [],
error: []
};
export default function(state=initalState, action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case "USERS_POST_PENDING":{
            return {...state, fetching: true,}
        }
        case "USERS_POST_FULFILLED":{
              return {...state, fetching: false,fetched: true, users:[...state.users, action.payload],}
        }
        case "USERS_POST_REJECTED":{
            return {...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload,}
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**src/reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import usersReducer from './usersReducer';
import tweetsReducer from './tweetsReducer';
export default combineReducers({
    users: usersReducer,
    tweets: tweetsReducer,
})
```

**src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import promise from 'redux-promise-middleware';
import reducers from './reducers/index';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import Layout from './components/layout';


const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(promise(),thunk, logger,loadingBarMiddleware()));
const app = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
        <Layout />
</Provider>
    ,app);
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: you are missing dispatch and reducers part of redux.

Comment: At first, you need to use a middleware for the async request, second you should either store the state in redux store or return the promise from action creators and setState in the component, I suppose this might help you a bit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47541032/how-to-make-post-request-using-react-redux-and-axios/47588228#47588228

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you can set the state of a component from outside of the component.
You should probably pass the handle function from layout.js to userActions.js

So the code should become:

**src/actions/userActions.js**

```
export function postUsers(username, password, errors, errorFunction) {
let users = {
    username,
    password,
};
let self = this;
return{
    type: "USERS_POST",
    payload: axios({
        method:'POST',
        url: url,
        data: users,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    })
        .then(success => {
            console.log('sucesssssssss', success)
        })
        .catch(({response}) => {
           errorFunction(response.data);
        })

    }
}
```

**src/components/layout.js**

```
    ...
        handlePostUsers(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.postUsers(
        this.state.username,
        this.state.password,
        this.state.errors,
        (responseData)=>{this.setState({errors: responseData})
        });
}
    ...
```