# how to post data in react es6 with axios using actions

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, post, axios

i am trying to post data using axios. i can get the api call to work but the problem i have is processing the data on the server side. the normal `$_POST` paramater in php is empty.

I have the following action

```
export const UPDATE_CONTENT = 'update_content';

export function updateContent(values) {
    console.log(values);
    let obj = {};
    obj['params'] = values;
    console.log(obj);
    const request = axios.post(`/api/admin/rename/content/management/format/json`,JSON.stringify(values));
    return {
        type: UPDATE_CONTENT,
        payload: request
    };
}
```

`values` is a key value object

```
{content : "<p>html text</p>",id:"21"}
```

when i post the using like `axios.post(`url`,values);` the request parameter is shown as payload and the `$_POST` on server side is empty.

when i use `JSON.stringify`, `$_POST` is not empty but it does not get sent as proper key value pairs on the request. i get the below

```
Array
(
    [{"id":"21","content":"<p>html text</p>"}
)
```

so in the server side i have to do `$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`

how can i fix this so i dont have to do `$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`

Comment: You might need to read this too, to fix another error that is there on frontend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47541032/handling-async-request-with-react-redux-and-axios/47588228#47588228.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `axios` serializes JavaScript objects to JSON and hence  it can only be read from `"php://input"` using `file_get_contents("php://input")`. Check the **[documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format)**

If you want to avoid it you can send the data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format instead

You can do it by using `URLSearchParams` like

```
var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('content', '<p>html text</p>');
params.append('id', '21');
axios.post(`/api/admin/rename/content/management/format/json`,params);
```

or you can use the [`querystring`](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format) module as follows:

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
axios.post('/api/admin/rename/content/management/format/json', querystring.stringify({"id":"21","content":"<p>html text</p>"}));
```

However after fixing this you will need to handle async actions in action creator in client side. Refer [Handling async request with React, Redux and Axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47541032/handling-async-request-with-react-redux-and-axios/47588228#47588228) for solving that issue