# React-Redux: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am getting Unhandled Rejection (Error): Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
I want to call the "news api" endpoint to fetch the news and render them on the page.

Here is my code for action:

```js
import * as types from './newsApiTypes';

const API_KEY = "6c78608600354f199f3f13ddb0d1e71a";

export const getNewsAPI = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'API_REQUEST',
      options: {
        method: 'GET',
        endpoint: `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=${API_KEY}`,
        actionTypes: {
          success: types.GET_NEWS_API_SUCCESS,
          error: types.GET_NEWS_API_ERROR
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Here is my code for reducer:

```js
import * as types from '../actions/newsApiTypes';

const initialState = {
  newNews: []
};

const getNewsAPIReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.GET_NEWS_API_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, newNews: action.data };

    case types.GET_NEWS_API_ERROR:
      return { ...state, error: action.data };

    default: {
      return state;
    };
  };
};

export default getNewsAPIReducer;
```

Here is my code for action types:

```js
export const GET_NEWS_API = 'GET_NEWS_API';
export const GET_NEWS_API_SUCCESS = 'GET_NEWS_API_SUCCESS';
export const GET_NEWS_API_ERROR = 'GET_NEWS_API_ERROR';
```

Here is my Index.js with creating store with applyMiddleware:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';

import App from './components/app';
import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('.container')
);
```

Here is my code for root reducers:

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import NewsReducer from './reducer_news';
import KickstarterReducer from './reducer_kickstarter';
import NewsApiReducer from './newsApiReducer.js';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  news: NewsReducer,
  kickstarters: KickstarterReducer,
  newNews: NewsApiReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Could anyone please help me why I am getting that unhandled error?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your `redux config` file / module ?

Comment: are you using any middleware? if no then check this ans [why do we need middleware for async flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570758/why-do-we-need-middleware-for-async-flow-in-redux)

Comment: @PritishVaidya I updated my post. Please take a look.

Comment: @MayankShukla Yes I am using it. Please take a look at the updated post.

Comment: your action looks like it is using `redux-thunk` but your config says otherwise..

Comment: @Eunicorn, This could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47541032/handling-async-request-with-react-redux-and-axios/47588228#47588228. you seem to be mixing the code syntax for redux-thunk and redux-promise

Comment: Your action looks like it is supposed to work with an API middleware instead of redux-promise.

Where you trying something like [redux-api-middleware](https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware) ?

Answer (score 1):

A great article that can help is [redux 4 ways](https://medium.com/react-native-training/redux-4-ways-95a130da0cdc).

Regarding the code.

### With redux-promise (which I see that you are using now) you should write:

```
export const getNewsAPI = () => {
  return {
      type: 'API_REQUEST',
      options: {
        method: 'GET',
        endpoint: `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=${API_KEY}`,
        actionTypes: {
          success: types.GET_NEWS_API_SUCCESS,
          error: types.GET_NEWS_API_ERROR
        }
      }
```

### Or, with redux-thunk:

Instead of:

```
export const getNewsAPI = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'API_REQUEST',
      options: {
        method: 'GET',
        endpoint: `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=${API_KEY}`,
        actionTypes: {
          success: types.GET_NEWS_API_SUCCESS,
          error: types.GET_NEWS_API_ERROR
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Use:

```
function actionCreator() {
  return {
          type: 'API_REQUEST',
          options: {
            method: 'GET',
            endpoint: `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=${API_KEY}`,
            actionTypes: {
              success: types.GET_NEWS_API_SUCCESS,
              error: types.GET_NEWS_API_ERROR
            }
          }  
      }
}
```

and:

```
export const getNewsAPI = () => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(actionCreator())
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, even with your answer, I still get the same error.

Comment: And you use redux-thunk? I see redux-promise in your code . I added code for redux-promise to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your action looks like it is using `redux-thunk` but your config says otherwise.

I'm new to react as well so I'm not 100% sure, but try this configuration (after installing `redux-thunk` of course):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';

import App from './components/app';
import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, ReduxPromise)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('.container')
);
```