# Redux thunk , Connect ,ApplyMiddlerware ,

Tags: redux, react-redux

- Could you please more elaborate into the following questions ??
         1 - react-redux is already provides the 
         connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
         Then why there is use of middleware and redux-thunk,As per my
         understanding this connect function would suffice to get the
         state from the store and dispatching the events from the
         component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With plain Redux functionality, your action creators must be plain object and hence you cannot make async calls in action creators or dispatch multiple actions from one action creators, `middlewares` are useful here

According to the docs:

> `Middleware` is the suggested way to extend Redux with custom
>   functionality. Middleware lets you wrap the store's dispatch method
>   for fun and profit. The key feature of middleware is that it is
>   composable. Multiple middleware can be combined together, where each
>   middleware requires no knowledge of what comes before or after it in
>   the chain.
>
> The most common use case for middleware is to **support asynchronous
>   actions** without much boilerplate code or a dependency on a library
>   like Rx. It does so by letting you dispatch async actions in addition
>   to normal actions.

`redux-thunk` lets the action creators invert control by dispatching functions. They would receive dispatch as an argument and may call it asynchronously. Such functions are called `thunks`. Another example of middleware is `redux-promise`. It lets you dispatch a `Promise async action`, and dispatches a normal action when the Promise resolves.

You might look at the following example to understand how to use [`redux-thunk to make async calls`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47541032/handling-async-request-with-react-redux-and-axios/47588228#47588228)