# Why to do I get error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to get redux working with my application, but there is the problem with me getting error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

I am new to redux, as I saw the problem is usually because people did not use applyMiddlewear, but I did it and do not understand why my code keeps getting this mistake.

My action that is probably getting mistake:

```
export function wordsAreFetching(bool){
return{
    type: 'WORDS_ARE_FETCHING',
    areFetching: bool
}



export function wordsFetchData(parsed) {
return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(wordsAreFetching(true));

    fetch('APICALL(here is url actually)', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json"
        },body: JSON.stringify({
            words: parsed
        })
    })
        .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error(response.statusText);
            }

            dispatch(wordsAreFetching(false));

            return response;
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((items) => dispatch(wordsFetchDataSuccess(items)))
        .catch(() => dispatch(wordsHasErrored(true)));
};
console.log(this.props.items)
}
```

My combine reducers file:

```
export default combineReducers({
word,
wordsAreFetching,
wordsFetchHasErrored
});
```

My store creation:

```
export default function configureStore(initialState) {
return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
}
```

How I call:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return {
    items: state.items,
    hasErrored: state.wordsFetchHasErrored,
    areFetching: state.wordsAreFetching
};
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetchData: (parse) => dispatch(wordsFetchData(parse))
    };
 };

componentDidMount = () => {
       this.props.fetchData(this.state.filterArray);
    }
```

Comment: show us where `wordsAreFetching ` is defined

Comment: @JoeLloyd see the updated question

Comment: Possibly this post will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47541032/handling-async-request-with-react-redux-and-axios/47588228#47588228

Answer (score 0):

You have mess in your code.

Redux has following main parts:

1. [Actions](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions) which should be plain objects having `type` property. Actions can be created using [action creators](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions#action-creators). Action creators just return action (plain objects). Or you can use bound action creators which also dispatches, like `wordsFetchData`.

   As of your code following functions should be acion creators:

   - `wordsAreFetching(bool)`
   - `wordsFetchData`
   - `wordsFetchDataSuccess`
   - `wordsHasErrored`
2. [Reducers](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers) accepts state and action and return state. I don't see any reducer in your code.

This call is incorrect

```
export default combineReducers({
    word,
    wordsAreFetching,
    wordsFetchHasErrored
});
```

All above function are action creators and shouldn't be placed in `combineReducers` call.

`mapDispatchToProps` should look like

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetchData: (parse) => wordsFetchData(parse)(dispatch)
    };
};
```

As `wordsFetchData` returns fucntion which takes `dispatch` as argument.